# Text change in Advanced Customs Fields

Tags: plugins, customization

I have edited the website which is not created by me.
There is advanced customs fields used for entry data during the post/page creation(wordpress custom editor). After that, the value of entered text is shown on the publicated page in the table, but table has the labels for entered data.

I was wondering how can I change the labels in any php file, but cannot find anything.
I would be gratefull for any tips,

Thank you,
Raf

Answer (score 1):

The data from Advanced Custom Fields is usually displayed on your site via template files from the active theme. This [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) page explains which template files are used for each type of page.

You can see the active theme by logging into the WP Admin and visiting the Appearance → Themes screen.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to edit front-page.php but it seems it doesn`t exist...

Comment: Maybye, do you know which file is responsible for wordpress custom page editor?

Comment: I suggest you search your theme files for the ACF field key to find the template file displaying it.